# Packages scrpage2 how to force header and footer on every page

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, scrpage2

I want to have footers and headers on every page of my report (which I do not want to change). But the header does not appear when I start a chapter or for other Chapter like parts (e.g. table of contents).
I tried to draw a line on every page into the header instead of using the scrpage2 header, but as far as I can see the missing chapter headers in scrpage2 are created by using white colour, hence it does not work as my black line gets overlayed by the white line.

> **Question**: Is there a way to force the scrpage2 headings to appear on every page?

Here is a minimal working example to illustrate the problem with the chapters.

```
\documentclass{report}   
\usepackage[nouppercase,headsepline,footsepline,plainfootsepline]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
%\ihead{(Document title)}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}% Optional argument controls chapter-starting pages

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\newpage
\chapter {Introduction1}
\newpage
\chapter{Introduction2}
\newpage
Test
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chapter pages uses page style `plain` by default. If there should be a line below of the header on plain pages too, add option `plainheadsepline`.

Note that package `scrpage2` is outdated. So here is an example with its successor `scrlayer-scrpage`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[
  markcase=noupper,
  headsepline,plainheadsepline,
  footsepline,plainfootsepline
]{scrlayer-scrpage}% activates pagestyle scrheadings automatically
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead*{(Document title)}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}

\title{Header Footer}
\author{adp2018dik }
\date{October 2018}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\chapter {Introduction1}
\newpage
\chapter{Introduction2}
\newpage
Test
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that `\ofoot*{\pagemark}` is a short version of `\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}`.

---

The same with the outdated package `scrpage2`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[
  nouppercase,
  headsepline,plainheadsepline,
  footsepline,plainfootsepline
]{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead[(Document title)]{(Document title)}
\ofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}

\title{Header Footer}
\author{adp2018dik }
\date{October 2018}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\chapter {Introduction1}
\newpage
\chapter{Introduction2}
\newpage
Test
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot the second version worked like a charm.